# Is it possible to define off-shell spinors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, dirac-equation, spinors

For the sake of concreteness, let us consider the [Dirac spinor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spinor) $u_s(\boldsymbol p)$. Is it possible to covariantly extend this to a function $u_s(p)$, such that it matches $u_s(\boldsymbol p)$ on the hyperboloid $p^2=m^2$?

I'm not sure what properties I would like $u_s(p)$ to have, so I leave it a bit arbitrary. For example, we may want to ask
$$
D(R)u(p)=u(Rp)
$$
for all $p\in\mathbb R^4$ and $R$ a rotation matrix (which may include [space inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)#Quantum_field_theory)?). We could even perhaps extend this to boosts as well as rotations, but the former mix the $s$ components and so I guess this gets trickier.

We want $u(p)$ to be a solution of $(\not p-m)u(p)=0$ whenever $p$ is on-shell (but not for general $p$, because $\text{det}(\not p-m)=(p^2-m^2)^2$, which means that for off-shell momenta, there are no non-trivial solutions).

Finally, I'm not sure if we could ask for $u_s(p)$ to be an [helicity eigenstate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicity_basis) $hu_\pm(p)=\pm \frac12 u_\pm(p)$, because for off-shell momenta, I don't think $h=\boldsymbol p\cdot\boldsymbol J/m$ is well-defined (and/or covariant).

---

Moreover, can we say something about higher spin polarisation vectors?

Comment: It is a quite interesting question, but you didn't tell why you are interested in it nor the context. Just a minor comment: the first condition you wished to require isn't actually satisfied on-shell, generically. You are missing the action of the so-called Wigner rotation on the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: As I see it, the Dirac equation implies the Klein-Gordon equations. Therefore since $u(p)$ is by definition a solution of the Dirac equation, it must also be a solution of the Klein-Gordon equation, aka on shell. Or do you mean something completely different?

Comment: @TwoBs Thank you :-) I don't really have a context nor motivation  (besides, perhaps, to study general properties of the spinorial representation without reference to equations of motion, if that makes sense). In regards to the transformation properties of the object $u_s(\vec p)$, I believe you are right, but I remain somewhat skeptic: see, please, [this old question of mine](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/273621/what-are-the-actual-transformation-properties-of-dirac-spinors-u-sigmap), especially the last line: if you could answer it, you'd make me really happy!

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I don't really want $u(p)$, for general $p$, to be the solution of Dirac's equation (nor, therefore, Klein-Gordon's), because if $p^2\neq m^2$, then the only solution of $(\not p-m)u(p)=0$ is $u(p)\equiv 0$, that is, there are no non-trivial solutions. If I keep $p$ off-shell, then $u(p)$ cannot be the solution to Dirac's equation. I hope I made myself clear :-)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform the polarizations can be defined easily with no reference to equation of motion, it's well known. I will post it here or in the old question within a couple of days. As for the analytic extension off shell I will add some useful comments in a tentative answer soon.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I have just answered your old question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/273621/what-are-the-actual-transformation-properties-of-dirac-spinors-u-sigmap that is related to the present one. As you can see from the length of the answer, I have at the moment no strength left, so that I will address the present question in the next days, maybe ...

Comment: I think that something is possible but $p$ must be timelike and an associated mass function should be used $m(p) = (-p^\mu p_\mu)^{1/2}$. The idea is the following. Consider the pure Lorentz transformation necessary to pass from the rest frame of $p$ to the laboratory frame, $\Lambda(p)$. It is well defined if $p$ is timelike. Next consider the inverse of the representation $\pi: SL(2,C)\to SO^+(1,3)$. There is a sign to fix, however $[\pi^{-1}(\Lambda(p))]^a_s$ fixes a pair ($s=1,2$) Weyl spinors. This is one component of your $u(p)$

Comment: The other component is obtained passing to the other representation of Weyl spinors, using the route to decompose Dirac spinors into a pair of Weyl spinors. I do not understand if the problem with the sign really matters.

Comment: @ValterMoretti it seems to me that, actually, it very simple: the standard spinor is $u(\boldsymbol p,m)$. So it suffices to define $u(p)\equiv u(\boldsymbol p,\sqrt{p\cdot p})$. In other words, the standard spinors depend explicitly on $\boldsymbol p$ and implicitly on $m$. To get an object that depends explicitly on $p^\mu$, we only need to let $m(p)=\sqrt{p\cdot p}$ as you propose. So yes: what you say is essentially the same as in the answer below.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have seen just now your answer below...sorry I am reading and writing using my phone is not so comfortable...

Comment: @Valter Moretti and AccidetalFouierTransform: Actually, I think that this, $m\rightarrow \sqrt{p^2}$, is not the useful way to go off-shell. Indeed, the sum over the polarizations, aka the resulting numerator of the propagator, would not longer be analytic (and linear in particular) in the 4-momentum off-shell. It would be something like $p_\mu\gamma^\mu- \sqrt{p^2}$. This is too bad, as it would introduce spurious non-analyticities in the scattering amplitudes. I think the correct/useful way of proceeding is not getting rid of the mass introducing new non-analyticities.

Comment: I am not too sure what the most convenient definition would be but I think that one doesn't want to mess up with analyticity of the scattering amplitudes. I would suggest that whatever you do you should keep the same analytic structure of the two-point function. In this case, the $\sum_\sigma u u^\dagger$ should give you $p_\mu \gamma^\mu- m$ with $p^0$ generically different than $\sqrt{p^2+m^2}$. This suggest that it's the numerator in the Kallen-Lehmann rep. for $\psi$ that defines such extension off-shell.

Comment: @TwoBs it is not about "convenience", because I dont intend to use $u(p)$ for anything in particular. There are no propagators, nor any analytic structure in this post. I dont what to use $u$ in a scattering amplitude. I just wanted a simple spinor to play around with.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Of course you are free to define whatever object you want, but the polarizations enter only in scattering amplitudes and their definition off-shell enters precisely in the propagators. The extension of $u(p)$ that you propose in the answer has any relevance in physics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most natural extension of $u_s(p)$ off the mass shell is to define this object as the solution of
$$
\left(\not p+\sqrt{p\cdot p\vphantom{A}}\,1_{4\times4}\right)u_s(p)=0 \tag{1}
$$
which clearly has at least one solution, because
$$
\det\left(\not p+\sqrt{p\cdot p\vphantom{A}}\,1_{4\times4}\right)=0\tag{2}
$$

In fact, it is not difficult to show that
$$
\mathrm{rank} \left(\not p+\sqrt{p\cdot p\vphantom{A}}\,1_{4\times4}\right)=2\tag{3}
$$
and therefore $(1)$ has exactly two (orthogonal) solutions. The equation $(1)$ is covariant, and therefore its solutions depend covariantly on $p^\mu$, and agree with the standard definition of the Dirac spinors by letting $m^2\equiv p^2$ with $m>0$.

We note that this definition of $u_s(p)$ is no more nor less general than the standard definition: here $u$ depends on the four components $p^\mu$, while in the standard case it depends on $\boldsymbol p$, but also implicitly on $m$, and therefore **both objects are actually the same thing** (the former case emphasises the dependence on $p^0$, while the latter emphasises the dependence on $m$, but the relation $p^0=p^0(m)$ can always be inverted to yield $m=m(p^0)$ and viceversa).

One very important remark is that this "extension" of $u$ off the mass-shell **has nothing to do** with what Weinberg does to define the off-shell propagator. In particular, Weinberg's approach is based on the extension
$$
\sqrt{\boldsymbol p^2+m^2}\to p^0\tag{4}
$$
or, equivalently, at the level of the spin sums,
$$
\sum_s u(\boldsymbol p)\bar u_s(\boldsymbol p)\to \not p-m\tag{5}
$$
with $p^0$ an off-shell Fourier variable.

Weinberg's extension, and the one that we are considering here, are completely unrelated. My "extension" above is not to be used in any practical application. It is not the polarisation vector of an off-shell particle. It is not a part of an off-shell propagator. As I said in the OP, I just wanted a spinor (in the abstract, algebraic sense) that depends on the four variables $p^\mu$. I didn't have any particular motivation for this question; rather, I just wanted to have a simple spinor to play around with. In my opinion, this answer addresses precisely that, and nothing else. If someone thinks that this answer is wrong, then it is because they didn't understand what I was trying to ask in the OP (of course, I am to blame: I should have been more clear about what I had in mind). As far as I'm concerned, this post answers my original question.

Again, and to reiterate: in this answer I did not extend the propagator off the mass-shell (and in the OP I didn't ask that). My "extension" has no usefulness for actual computations in QFT.

Comment: I should have commented here and instead I have put my comments below your original question. Please have a look.